# Access a private docker registry with ECS Fargate and Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I need my ECS Task definition to contain the credentials of my private Docker registry, using if possible a simple token, or, a user:password.

Below is my code:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "docker_registry_secret" {
  name_prefix = "/my_environment/registry/pwd"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "docker_registry_secret_version" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.docker_registry_secret.id
  secret_string = xxxMYTOKENxxx
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "password_policy_secretsmanager" {
  name = "${var.task_name}-secretsmanager"
  role = aws_iam_role.MY_ECS_ROLE.id

  policy = <<-EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": [
          "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
          "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.docker_registry_secret.arn}",
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_to_be_scheduled" {
  .....
  ....
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      "repositoryCredentials" : {
        "credentialsParameter" : aws_secretsmanager_secret.docker_registry_secret.arn
      },
      ....
      ....
  ])
}
```

However, when I launch my task, I have the following error on my ECS: **unable to unmarshal secret value of authorization data from asm**

I'm pretty sure the error is related to secret manager, but not sure where exactly. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like, your are using the wrong format of the stored secrets to your docker registry. The error leads me to believe that it is a non-validated JSON. What format is the secret stored in?

Comment: the format is a string such as "thisismytoken". Is it incorrect?

Comment: you need to store valid JSON within the secrets manager. The error, you received, means, that you pass a non-JSON string to the attribute for the credentialsParameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this answer can help someone else. I did two mistakes:

1. In my task definition, I only had the execution_role_arn field set. I forgot to add the task_role_arn.

```
# before

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_to_be_scheduled" {
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  ....
}

# after

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_to_be_scheduled" {
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.arn
  ....
}
```

2. I was using a token as the credentialsParameter instead of something such as {"username" : "gitlab-ci-token", "password" : "your-password"}

```
# before

container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      "repositoryCredentials" : {
        "credentialsParameter" : "any-token-as-string"
      },
   ....
}]

# after

container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      "repositoryCredentials" : {
        "credentialsParameter" : {"username" : "gitlab-ci-token", "password" : "your-password"}
      },
   ....
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem after i used :

```
"repositoryCredentials": {
        "credentialsParameter": {"username" : "xx" , "password" : "xxxxx"} 
        },
```

I'm trying to autheticate with nexus repository.

> Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error
> decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field
> RepositoryCredentials.RepositoryCredentials.CredentialsParameter of
> type string

Comment: I'm on the same boat, did you solve this?
As far as I can see you can only pass a parameter store arn for credentialsParameter. i don't get how the above solutions can work

Answer (score 1):

```
repositoryCredentials": {
    "credentialsParameter": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxx:secret:NexusContainerRegistryAccess-yVnAfJ"
    },
```

I solved by using secretmanager